# Access Requested Client from IUserService

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server

I have an existing database that holds user credentials as well a map of what applications those user credentials have access to. In identity server I have each application setup as a client and users can authenticate successful. However, any user gets authorized for any application. I am wondering if there is a way that I can access which client is being requested from my implementation of IUserService? This way I can check if they are authorized for that app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IdentityServer allows for custom validation of the requests via the `ICustomRequestValidator` interface. You can implement this and return an error to prevent a user from getting a token for a client.

Let us know on the github issue tracker if you have more feedback on this.

Comment: Thanks Brock I'll take a look into it. I did a quick look through the samples and the wiki on github and wasn't able to find any documentation on this. Do you happen to have a blog post on custom validators?

Comment: No, there's no sample of this. I'll open an issue on github to have one added.

Comment: @BrockAllen - do you have a link for this issue - is it issue 750 by any chance?